# Unable to deposit tokens into the contract when the user's balance within the contract is 0

Tags: web3js

I'm working on a web-based interaction with a smart contract that allows users to deposit and withdraw tokens. I've noticed that when the user's balance within the contract is 0, they cannot deposit tokens using the web interface. However, if I first deposit tokens into the contract through Remix, then the user can deposit tokens using the web interface. I use ganache VM.

Here's the deposit function in the smart contract:

```
function deposit(uint256 _amount) public payable whenNotPaused {
    require(_amount > 0, "deposit amount must be more than 0!");
    usdtToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
    playerBalances[msg.sender] += _amount;
    emit DepositMessage(msg.sender, msg.value);
}
```

And here's the relevant JavaScript code for the web interface:

```
async function deposit(amount) {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    
    const amountWei = web3.utils.toWei(amount, 'mwei');
    console.log(amountWei);
    
    await usdtInstance.methods.approve(redGameAddress, amountWei).send({ from: accounts[0] });
    await redGameInstance.methods.deposit(amountWei).send({ from: accounts[0], gas: 60000 })
        .once('transactionHash', (hash) => {
        console.log('Transaction hash:', hash);
        })
        .once('receipt', (receipt) => {
        console.log('Transaction receipt:', receipt);
        updateBalance();
        });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "user's balance within the contract"? Are you talking about the mapping?
Also, what is the error you are getting?  Share the console.log data while transaction is executed

Comment: When it fails what's the error message? The gas settings `gas: 60000` seems a bit low. The first time a user calls deposit the storage for that user will be initialized and it will cost something extra in gas.